# JQuery - find first sibling matches selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, siblings

How can i get the first (next) element in the list that matches the selector ?

Example:

```
<table>
  <tr class="test"><td>not this one</td></tr>
  <tr><td><a title="test">click</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td>not this one</td></tr>
  <tr class="test"><td>this one</td></tr>
  <tr class="test"><td>ignore this as well</td></tr>
</table>

$("a").on('click', function(eve){
  $(this).parents("tr").???(".test").toggle();
});
```

---

edit

I need the following row. siblings gets others as well (like the first row)

Comment: what are you trying to do??

Comment: i have some dynamic rows that are toggled on and off by the prev' row. i can't use 'next()' since i can't tell which of the rows i will have - and how many.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/) to get following siblings of an element and [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) to get first matched element.

Try this:

```
$("a").on('click', function(eve){
  $(this).parents("tr").nextAll(".test:first").toggle();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/W53sh/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You may try using jQuery eq();

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .eq() method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that set. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the set. [Documentation on jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
<table>
  <tr class="test"><td>not this one</td></tr>
  <tr><td><a title="test">click</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td>not this one</td></tr>
  <tr class="test"><td>this one</td></tr>
  <tr class="test"><td>ignore this as well</td></tr>
</table>
```

The code would **select the 2º sibling with the class "test" of the < tr > that is one of the parents to the clicked < a >** (red this reversely and you got your code):

```
$("a").on('click', function(){
  $(this).parents("tr").siblings(".test").eq(1).toggle();
});
```

**[Check the Pen!](http://codepen.io/teefars/pen/ZGgMvK?editors=101)**

Comment: Doesn't 100% answer OP's question as 1) OP asked for the next sbilings thus `nextAll` instead of `siblings` (also select those before) and 2) he asked for the next one (first one) thus `eq(0)` instead of `eq(1)`. Although you mentioned it selects the second one, it's still better practice to directly answer the asked question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.next()` selector:

`Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.`

For your case, use

`$(this).parents("tr").next().next()`

or

`$(this).closest("tr").next().next()`